# What the meaning of $\sigma$ (s) in $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: measure-theory, math-history

Why a mathematician write a "s"/$\sigma$ in $\sigma$-algebra in place of another letter? Does it have anything to do with the word "sum", like $\Sigma$ or $\int$ for a sum?

Comment: Exactly; Because the Greek [Sigma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma) is the "origin" of modern s. See e.g. [Socrates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socrates) : Greek: Σωκράτης.

Comment: Capital "$\sigma$" $(\Sigma)$ usually goes for "sum"'. In this specific case, it stands for ``countable union", instead of the "finite union" assumed for an algebra.

Comment: When I see "$\sigma$" anywhere, I think "countable union". This applies to the terms "$\sigma$-algebra", "$\sigma$-finite" and "$\sigma$-compact. Also $F_\sigma$ means the union of countably many closed sets. Apparently $\sigma$ comes from the German "Summe" for union!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kenny Wong is right.

This notation came to us from German mathematicians around 1900.   (Maybe Hausdorff was the first to use it?  I don't remember.)  The Greek letters $\sigma$ and $\delta$ denoted (closed under, or constructed by) countable unions and countable intersections, repectively.

The Greek letter $\sigma$ corresponts to the Latin letter $S$, which is the initial of the German word *Summe*, meaning *union*.

The Greek letter $\delta$ corresponts to the Latin letter $D$, which is the initial of the German word *Durchschnitt*, meaning *intersection*.